# Java Api for Apache Stanbol

Tags: apache-stanbol

I am working on Apache Stanbol.I have gone through the documentation of stanbol.All they have given only rest api for every stanbol component.Is there any java api for stanbol using which i can write code in java to execute all the stanbol component's work ?Also is any examples are available?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Java client for Apache Stanbol?

Please refer this: https://github.com/zaizi/apache-stanbol-client

Comment: Thanks Dileepa.I will check it.